# np.exp overflow workaround

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following equation:

```
result = (A * np.exp(b * (t - t0))) / (1 + np.exp(c * (t - t0)))
```

I feed in an array of t values to get results out. `A, b, c, t0` are all constants (`b` and `c` are very large, `t0` is small but not as small as b and c are large). The problem is, I run into an overflow error because the exponential value quickly gets much too large to fit into a float64 beyond a certain range of `t`. I'm trying to find a workaround to this while still maintaining a decent level of precision. The `result` value is well within the range of a float64 container, however the overly large intermediate values of the `np.exp` calculation prevent me from getting as far as the result.

Some thoughts I had:

- Scale down the t input to be able to get the desired range of values, and then de-scale the output so the result is correct
- Convert the exponential to a log function

However I'm not sure how to implement either of these ideas, or if they would actually work.

Essential this problem boils down to `result = np.exp(a) / np.exp(b)`, where a and b are in the range of 100-1000. `np.exp(709)` results in 8.2e307, right at the limit of a float64, but I have larger values that need to feed into it. While the comparison of the two exponentials produces a reasonable value, the exponentials themselves are too large to be calculated.

Comment: Why do you need numbers to such a level of precision? `8.2e307` is indistinguishable from `np.inf` in any practical application I can think of.

Comment: If you need such large numbers with high precision you might need to move to an arbitrary precision floating point library. I've thought of adding arbitrary precision floats to Numpy before but it's a non-trivial task and I haven't been sufficiently motivated to spend the time :(

Comment: FWIW SageMath provides arbitrary precision floating point support in Python. Unfortunately, depending on your platform and your overall project, Sage can be non-trivial to install and use as a dependency, though we are working on improving that. Separating the MPFR Python wrappers out to a separate package is also on the horizon for me (though such packages may already exist too)

Comment: You could add a condition, that if `c*(t-t0)` is big enough, you disregard the 1 and calculate using simplified formula.

Comment: @roganjosh While `8.2e307` is indistinguishable from `np.inf`, the comparison `8.2e307 / 7.5e305` results in a resonable and useful number. That's what I'm trying to get at, not the result of the exponential, but the comparison of two exponentials.

Comment: One obvious thing to do would be to cancel the `exp(c * (t-t0))`: `result = (A * np.exp((b-c) * (t - t0))) / (1 + np.exp(-c * (t - t0)))`. This will only overflow if the final result is too large.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes sense

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser For example: A=5, b=1e10, c=1e9, t0=1e-8, t=5e-8. That will give a valid result, but if t = 5e-7 there's an overflow.

Comment: Am I missing something or why can you not take the log of both sides (ignoring the +1), compute the ratio (which is now a difference), and then convert back?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I think that's what Sam Mason described below. That does seem to work. (I'm rusty with the maths...) It is an approximation, but over the scale I'm concerned with the error isn't significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keeping everything in the log scale is the common solution to this sort of thing.  at least that's what we do in statistics where you're often down in the 1e-10000 range, especially at the start before you're any where near convergence.  for example, all the `scipy` probability density functions have `logpdf` variants which work in the log scale.

I think your expression would be rewritten something like:

```
d = t - t0
log_result = (np.log(A) + (b * d)) - np.logaddexp(0, c * d)
```

(untested)

Comment: I think you're on to something, but does the result need to be scaled back to the real value after re-working on the log scale? I get a very different result for a known, non-overflow value between the original equation and yours.

Comment: Nevermind - I just have to put the result back into an exponent. Rusty with the maths... That does seem to work!

Comment: @Sagasaki glad you got there!  it's worth checking out the other numerical stability helpers in numpy, e.g. `log1p` and so on.  John Cook has useful things to say about this https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/